# Transforming matrix inequality into LMI

Tags: optimization, control-theory, linear-matrix-inequality

Is there a variable change I could do in order to transform the matrix inequality below

$$A^T P A - P + Q + K^T B^T P A + A^T P B K + K^T(B^T P B + R) K \leq 0$$

into an LMI? My variables are positive definite matrix $P$ and non-invertible matrix $K$. In my specific case, $K$ is a $3 \times 6$ matrix. All other matrices are given. Thank you all very much!

Comment: That expression is not correct (as it isn't symmteric). This discrete-time LQR LMI (when corrected...) is linearized using a standard "multiply with P from left and right, define KP as Y, perform Schur complement" strategy

Comment: Thank you very much @JohanLöfberg. Could you please be a bit more specific on how to perform the Schur complement strategy?

Comment: I advice yo to read https://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/lmibook/lmibook.pdf to see how Schur completements are used as the bread and butter for LMI reformulations. This case is probably covered explicitly. BTW, it should be multiply with $P^{-1}$ and thus $Y = KP^{-1}$.